# Does the mempool size as reported by Blockchain.com include the size of txs only?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mempool, memory, blockchain-explorer, getmemorypool

Does the mempool size as reported by  (for instance Blockchain.com) include the sum of the 'size' of transactions only?  Or does it also include the overhead (due to indexes, allocation overhead, metadata)?

for instance, the ancestor-descendant mappings that it calculates and updates at every incoming transaction, is the size of the data structure used to store that also included in the total size as reported here https://www.blockchain.com/charts/mempool-size or here https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#0,24h